# ESP8266 and I2C

Tags: esp8266, accelerometer, gyro, nodemcu

I want to read data from five equal devices via I2C. Master is ESP8266 microcontroller and slaves are five MPU5060. The problem is that they have equal addresses. I've seen a lot of answers about how to solve it, but they are all about multiplexers. How can I do it by the software part?

Answer (score 1):

**Not possible.**

Software alone cannot differentiate same slave devices with same I2C addresses.

It is wise to go ahead with the working solutions. Multiplexers are a good approach realised using discretes or readymade solution.

Edit 1:.

The ADD pin can be modified to atleast create two different addresses.
[image]

Comment: If the MPU5060 responds to ADD pin changes on the fly ( so it is not latched in only at powerup ) then you only need to select one of the MPUs with a GPIO pin so that only one of them is at one address at a given time.

Comment: @Justme datasheet doesn't say it.. but it is a suggestion OP should check it for sure. either the OP should experiment or write to the manufacturer.